# javax.naming.AuthenticationException

Tags: java, active-directory, ldap, kerberos, gssapi

I'm trying to create a context for ActiveDirectory (client and server are both windows), using my Windows credentials with NTLM.

This is my code:

```
public void func() {
    try {
      URL configURL = getClass().getResource("jaas_ntlm_configuration.txt");
        System.setProperty("java.security.auth.login.config", configURL.toString());

        // If the application is run on NT rather than Unix, use this name
        String loginAppName = "MyConfig";

        // Create login context
        LoginContext lc = new LoginContext(loginAppName, new SampleCallbackHandler());

        // Retrieve the information on the logged-in user
        lc.login();

        // Get the authenticated subject
        Subject subject = lc.getSubject();

        System.out.println(subject.toString());

        Subject.doAs(subject, new JndiAction(new String[] { "" }));
    }
    catch (LoginException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

class JndiAction implements java.security.PrivilegedAction {
    private String[] args;

    public JndiAction(String[] origArgs) {
        this.args = (String[])origArgs.clone();
    }

    public Object run() {
        performJndiOperation(args);
        return null;
    }

    private static void performJndiOperation(String[] args) {

        // Set up environment for creating initial context
        Hashtable env = new Hashtable(11);

        env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");

        // Must use fully qualified hostname
        env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldap://server:389");

        // Request the use of the "GSSAPI" SASL mechanism
        // Authenticate by using already established Kerberos credentials
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "GSSAPI");

        try {
            /* Create initial context */
//          DirContext ctx = new InitialDirContext(env);

              // Create the initial context
            DirContext ctx = new InitialLdapContext(env, null);


            // Close the context when we're done
            ctx.close();
        } catch (NamingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

And my jaas_ntlm_configuration.txt file contains:

```
MyConfig { com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
useTicketCache=true
doNotPrompt=false;
};
```

When I'm trying to initiate the context, i'm getting the following exception:

```
javax.naming.AuthenticationException: GSSAPI [Root exception is javax.security.sasl.SaslException: Final handshake failed [Caused by GSSException: Token had invalid integrity check (Mechanism level: Corrupt checksum in Wrap token)]]
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.sasl.LdapSasl.saslBind(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClient.authenticate(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.connect(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getUsingURL(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getUsingURLs(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getLdapCtxInstance(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getInitialContext(Unknown Source)
        at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(Unknown Source)
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(Unknown Source)
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.init(Unknown Source)
        at javax.naming.ldap.InitialLdapContext.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at JndiAction.performJndiOperation(JndiAction.java:204)
        at JndiAction.run(JndiAction.java:181)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Unknown Source)
        at MyTest.Do(MyTest.java:59)
        at MyTest.main(MyTest.java:68)
Caused by: javax.security.sasl.SaslException: Final handshake failed [Caused by GSSException: Token had invalid integrity check (Mechanism level: Corrupt checksum in Wrap token)]
        at com.sun.security.sasl.gsskerb.GssKrb5Client.doFinalHandshake(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.security.sasl.gsskerb.GssKrb5Client.evaluateChallenge(Unknown Source)
        ... 18 more
Caused by: GSSException: Token had invalid integrity check (Mechanism level: Corrupt checksum in Wrap token)
        at sun.security.jgss.krb5.WrapToken_v2.getData(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.jgss.krb5.WrapToken_v2.getData(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5Context.unwrap(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl.unwrap(Unknown Source)
        ... 20 more
```

Can someone help me with this issue?

Comment: That looks like Kerberos not NTLM - have you tried something like the Tagish library - it makes native calls to authenticate against NTML: http://dione.zcu.cz/~toman40/JAASModule/doc/tagish/index.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are actually using a Kerberos authentication..
If this is what you mean to do, I can tell you how I managed to get it working :

```
- add somewhere a file called krb5.conf with inside :

[libdefaults]
default_realm = YOUR_REALM
default_tkt_enctypes = arcfour-hmac-md5
default_tgs_enctypes = arcfour-hmac-md5
permitted_enctypes = arcfour-hmac-md5

dns_lookup_kdc = true
dns_lookup_realm = false

[realms]
YOUR_REALM = {
kdc = KERBEROS_SERVER
default_domain = YOUR_REALM
}
```

- add this lines to your code :

  System.setProperty("java.security.krb5.conf",PATH_TO_KRB5CONF_FILE);
  System.setProperty("sun.security.krb5.principal", PRINCIPAL_NAME_WITHOUT_DOMAIN);

If you don't know your Kerberos Server you can't launch  klist from commandline, and take the service who uses the LDAP protocol (LDAP/server@domain -> server).

If it still does not work try to add

```
System.setProperty("sun.security.krb5.debug", "true");
```

and post the output.